# Download Xcode simulator directly

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator, xcode-6.2

I have downloaded Xcode 6.2 today which replaced previous Xcode 6.1
now to use simulator 7.1 & 8.1 it asks to download both simulators , but for some reason after trying 4-5 times it shows network issues in downloading or request time out (note: in n/w diagnostic after it shows net is working properly)

so is there any direct link from where i can download the simulator package directly or somewhere at least it shows progress in percentage/size instead just a bar

if it's not possible i have read about copying the older simulator to new Xcode so how can i place the old simulator(7.1 & 8.1) in Xcode 6.2 that it works directly without downloading again

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/manually-install-ios-simulators-in-xcode-f7e4bbe50753

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Clicking on Download in Xcode didn't do anything - the progress bar did not progress (does that make it a regress bar?).

This is what worked for me:

1. Open Xcode, open preferences, go to the Components section.
2. Open the Console App, clear the console.
3. Go back to the Xcode preferences. Start the simulator download, then cancel it.
4. Now in the Console, you will see something about the cancellation with the download URL.
5. Copy the URL from the Console. Then in Terminal in some suitable scratch folder, download it:

   > `curl [the url you copied] -O` (the letter O, not a zero)
6. Finally, copy this file to ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads
   Remove all *.dvtdownloadableindex files (maybe it doesn't matter, but I removed them).
7. In Xcode, in the Downloads section, start the Simulator download again, it should find the file you downloaded and install it.

How easy was that! Only 7 steps, hah!

Comment: Worked great!  I experimented by not removing the `*.dvtdownloadableindex` files in step 6, and the simulator installed fine.

Comment: That's also helped to download it at all. I have not very fast connection at home. So downloading was always incomplete with "timeout". This solution helped in my case as well. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't show any message in console area, you are referring to xcode's debug console right?

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha, he's referring to MacOS's `Console` app - you can find it  by pressing cmd+space and typing `console`

Comment: I do not have a Downloads folder in my ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode directory

Comment: @TashPemhiwa: just create a Downloads folder in  ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode before moving the dmg file. I did this and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @emp One suggestion: instead of using curl, open the URL in Safari. This way you'll be able to resume the download if it fails midway through.

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha cancel the download to see in the console.

Comment: Chris Vasselli is right. Just download from Safari - a lot easier to manage. Plus you can see the speed in Download popup. Easy to stop and resume, etc.

Comment: Hi @emp I tried the same 7 steps but didn't work for me. Does it is required to do the download on my Mac system? I have downloaded the simulators on the other system I have experimented with Xcode 8.2.1 and simulator for iOS 9.3 and iOS 8.4 plus try to install the Guides and Sample code. But no luck I am not able to install any of them with the above mentioned 7 steps Please help me.

Comment: Just to clarify, they don't mean the Xcode Console but the Console application (*not* the system Terminal either). Use spotlight to find it.. it's under Utilities/.

Comment: com.apple.dt.Xcode is now a bundle, not a folder. Same, with 'Show Package Contents', and create a 'Download' folder right there.

Comment: curl is GREAT.. could resume when download hanged!! And the best part that it's fun to trick XCode - I Love That Solution!!!

Comment: i dont have com.apple.dt.Xcode folder in caches, please help me where is the location now

Comment: FYI: as of Xcode 11 (11/2019) `sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode` with "Xcode >> Preferences >> Components", download/cancel (thanks @superquanganh) to read off the download URL along with `cp com.apple.pkg.*.dmg ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/` (thanks @emp) still works.

Comment: Apple is so cool to not support resuming of downloads while it is so common that 3GB file gets interrupted. Thanks you helped me out.

Comment: @Gary it's not working for me, I've Xcode 13 with M1 chip. It's directly downloading even I've kept the .dmg inside the ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/. I've also noticed nothing is getting downloaded in Downloads folder while the simulator is trying to download the  simulator.

Comment: @phatmann I don't even have com.apple.dt.Xcode folder in Caches

Comment: @Abdullah just create it manually.

Comment: @phatmann i did try by creating these folders manually but still Xcode do not detect the downloaded .dmg file for iOS 13.7 simulator

Comment: Perhaps new Xcode version works differently. Maybe someone will chime in with more info.

Comment: I dont have such folder at all

Comment: I dont see Component section. Did they rename it to Platforms?

Comment: @phatmann the work around here is to restart the xcode. This fixes the issue as xcode now detects the downloaded file .

Comment: I have Xcode 14.3. I downloaded Simulator 14.5. I placed the downloaded dmg in the newly created Downloads folder, but the Simulator doesn't show.

Comment: Not work on Xcode 15.0 (15A240d)

Answer (score 156):

To add iOS Simulator in XCode perform below steps:

- Download iOS Simulator from Below Link:
- After download completes, copy this file to ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads
  In some cases, we have to remove all *.dvtdownloadableindex files (maybe it doesn't matter, I didn't remove them).
- In case directory ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode don't have download folder then, just click `Show package content` create Downloads folder, before moving the dmg file.
- In Xcode, in the Downloads section, start the Simulator download again, it should find the file you downloaded and install it.

**(Newest on top.  only the latest revision is kept in the list.)**

- Simulator Link:

[iOS 17.4](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/iOS_17.4_Simulator_Runtime/iOS_17.4_Simulator_Runtime.dmg)

[iOS 17.2](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/iOS_17.2_Simulator_Runtime/iOS_17.2_Simulator_Runtime.dmg)

**iOS 17.0.1**

https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/iOS_17.0.1_Simulator_Runtime/iOS_17.0.1_Simulator_Runtime.dmg

**iOS 15.5**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK15_5-15.5.1.1653527639.dmg

**iOS 15.4**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK15_4-15.4.1.1650505652.dmg

**iOS 15.2**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK15_2-15.2.1.1643410298.dmg

**iOS 14.5**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK14_5-14.5.1.1621461325.dmg

**iOS 14.4**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK14_4-14.4.1.1611903691.dmg

**iOS 14.3**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK14_3-14.3.1.1611873653.dmg

**iOS 14.2**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK14_2-14.2.1.1605311653.dmg

**iOS 14.1**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK14_1-14.1.1.1604100028.dmg

**iOS 14.0**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK14_0-14.0.1.1604100028.dmg

**iOS 13.7**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK13_7-13.7.1.1599165590.dmg

**iOS 13.6**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK13_6-13.6.1.1597276955.dmg

**iOS 13.5**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK13_5-13.5.1.1591226335.dmg

**iOS 13.4**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK13_4-13.4.1.1586370836.dmg

**iOS 13.3**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK13_3-13.3.1.1580170331.dmg

**iOS 13.2**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK13_2-13.2.1.1575590084.dmg

**iOS 13.1**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK13_1-13.1.1.1571440502.dmg

**iOS 13.0**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK13_0-13.0.1.1571440502.dmg

**iOS 12.4**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK12_4-12.4.1.1568665771.dmg

**iOS 12.2**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK12_2-12.2.1.1557987768.dmg

**iOS 12.1**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK12_1-12.1.1.1543439531.dmg

**iOS 12.0**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK12_0-12.0.1.1537588161.dmg

**iOS 11.4**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK11_4-11.4.1.1527703358.dmg

**iOS 11.3**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK11_3-11.3.1.1524350608.dmg

**iOS 11.2**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK11_2-11.2.1.1516308624.dmg

**iOS 11.1**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK11_1-11.1.1.1510784422.dmg

**iOS 11.0**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK11_0-11.0.1.1508875951.dmg

**iOS 10.3.1**

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK10_3-10.3.1.1495751597.dmg

Comment: I followed the above steps but i got this error 'Could not download and install iOS 13.1 Simulator. Failed to mount image: no mountable file systems' Could you please help me to resolve it .

Comment: Which Xcode you are using and for that which simulator you are downloading?

Comment: Is there a link for iOS14 ?

Comment: Hi @SurajSonawane, is there any link for iOS 12.5.1 simulator? If you know please share.

Comment: @freezing_ URL updated for iOS 14. Please check now

Comment: This package is incompatible with this version of macOS.

Comment: @NsaghaKingsly, I have this issue too, I have a M1 MacBook Air, I think this issue relates to new Apple Arm Architecture.

Comment: for iso 15.0 simulator https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK15_0-15.0.1.1633542405.dmg

Comment: tip: if you want to make your life a little easier as downloading the dmg directly takes forever, i suggest using aria2. brew install aria2 && aria2c -x10 <DMG_LINK>

Comment: ios 15.5 link: https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK15_5-15.5.1.1653527639.dmg

Comment: Does anyone have link for iOS 16.0 and 16.1 simulators?

Comment: I downloaded iOS 11.2 and added it as instructed. Still I don't see iOS 11 in XCode>Preferences>Platforms

Comment: Is there a link for iOS 14.8?

Comment: @HassanTaleb hi bro, ios 17.2 link not works did you have its link?

Comment: @AminRezaew go to https://developer.apple.com/download/all/ and sign in, then press the link above or scroll down to iOS 17.2 Simulator Runtime and click 'iOS 17.2 Simulator Runtime.dmg'

Comment: @HassanTaleb Thank you bro it helped me=) i will give you upvote

Answer (score 28):

If someone is searching in 2019, I have a better solution than looking at messy Console app.

1/ Open Terminal and run `sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`
 to open Xcode in sudo mode.

2/ Xcode > Preferences > Components > Download then cancel the simulator you want to download.

3/ Go back to Terminal, it will log the Downloadable with the Simulator link, copy that to Safari to download it.

Comment: Simpler than the original answer. Thanks.

Comment: Much better solution :)

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: This does not work for me. I am using XCode 14.2

Answer (score 18):

Follow these steps to add a (new) simulator (Xcode 9 onwards)

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Add Additional Simulator**". That will open **'Device & Simulator'** window.
3. Switch to **'Simulator'** tab.
4. There are three field in simulator tab.
5. Click on **'+'** icon, on left bottom corner of window.
6. Simulator Name: *Enter simulator name here*
7. Device Type: *Select **iPad** from this dropdown list*
8. OS Version: *Select OS version from this dropdown list*
9. Click on **'Create'**

A new simulator will be added in your Simulator option list.

Look at this snapshot to understand flow of above steps:
[image]

And if there is no simulator/OS version in simulator list, you're looking for,

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Download Simulator**". That will open **'Component'** window (from Xcode >> Preferences).
3. Select/click simulator from list, which you need to download.

Look at this snapshot:
[image]

Comment: Why someone's upvoted this ? I don't get it. It didn't answer question at all.

Comment: 12 upvotes tell me this answer provides useful information for people finding this question, even if it does not directly answer the question itself.

Answer (score 15):

The download links for all Apple platform runtimes are available here:

https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/index2.dvtdownloadableindex

Runtimes for Apple platforms from 2022<sup>[1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes)</sup> can be installed with the `xcrun simctl runtime add` command:

```
xcrun simctl runtime add iOS_16_Simulator_Runtime.dmg
```

For earlier platforms use [xcodes](https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/xcodes):

```
sudo xcodes runtimes install "iOS 15.0"
```

The following command will show all available runtimes:

```
sudo xcodes runtimes
```

Comment: I tried this and got this error: `<unknown platform> (Unusable - Missing Signature: Error Domain=SimDiskImageErrorDomain Code=3 "Missing Signature" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing Signature, unusableErrorDetail=})`; Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Eddie what command are you running? You will get that error using the `xcrun simctl runtime add` command with iOS 15 and earlier.

Comment: I ran the `xcrun simctl` command, trying to add simulator 12

Comment: You can only use `xcrun simctl` with iOS 16 or later.

Comment: The question was about how to install older simulators. Even if I ran `xcodes runtimes install "iOS 12.0"`, it reports: `Error: Runtime iOS 12.0 is invalid or not downloadable`, so it seems your answer doesn't help.

Comment: That runtime is not available, you can use this:
`sudo xcodes runtimes install "iOS 12.4"`

Comment: I tried 12.4 and got this error after downloaded the dmg file: `Error: Failed executing: /usr/sbin/installer -pkg /path/to/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK12_4.pkg -target / (1).` When I tried to mount the dmg, run the pkg file, it showed an error: `This package is incompatible with this version of macOS`. I guess MacOS 13.2 (Ventura) remove support for ios prior to 13 and we can't help it.

Comment: I am able to successfully install the iOS 12.4 runtime on macOS 13.3.

Comment: I've updated to 13.3 and still the same error. Maybe it's because I'm using a M1 Mac?

Comment: I installed the runtime on two M1 Macs running macOS 12.5 and 13.3. Does your terminal have Full Disk Access? https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/xcodes/issues/272#issuecomment-1433495152

Comment: I've granted Full Disk Access and now it is installed completely. However, I still can't use it in xcode as there's no option to select the simulator (see: https://imgur.com/a/ddpBP52).

Comment: According to Apple Feedback, this means that the version of macOS does not support that runtime version.

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer! To install iOS 17 runtimes just use the command: `xcrun simctl runtime add iOS_17_beta_Simulator_Runtime.dmg` (after downloading .dmg file from Apple website)

Comment: Hi, sorry to bump an old thread. I tried this to install iOs 12.4 on XCode 14.3.1. It got installed and I can see it on the list. But I can't select it. The iOS version that can be used is only iOS 16. Can you help with this? Thank you.

Comment: It's possible to install unsupported runtimes, see the above comments.

Answer (score 14):

## ✅ Official Download from Apple - (Since Xcode 15)

1. You have to [login](https://developer.apple.com/account/) before downloading anything below.
2. You can find all Xcode dmg/xip files directly on https://developer.apple.com/download/all/ (requires Apple ID).
3. Simulator runtimes are in the collapsing menu of each corresponding Xcode.

Here is a list of all available runtimes for download:

[**Xcode 15**](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_15_beta/Xcode_15_beta.xip)

- [iOS 17 beta runtime](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/iOS_17_beta/iOS_17_beta_Simulator_Runtime.dmg)
- [watchOS 10 beta runtime](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/watchOS_10_beta/watchOS_10_beta_Simulator_Runtime.dmg)

---

###### Method 1:

You should copy the content in the downloaded DMG from:

```
{THE_MOUNTED_DMG_YOU_JUST_DOWNLOADED}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles
```

to

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles
```

---

###### Method 2:

Also, you can just use the `simctl` command to install it:

```
sudo xcrun simctl runtime add PATH_TO_THE_DOWNLIADED_DMG_FILE
```

Comment: What about older versions like iOS 13.7?

Comment: Ridiculously, only iOS 17 runtimes are available on the Apple Developer website.

Answer (score 5):

So a quick tip for the people who use a download manager to download the .dmg file and didn't manage to get it work.

Once you place the file inside the 'Downloads' folder,
Copy and paste the url somewhere and copy the file name alone.

( for me I was downloading iOS 9.3 so the url was -
https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/**com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK9_3-9.3.1.1460411551.dmg**

and rename the file you just copied to the 'Downloads' folder, even if it looks exactly the same.

I wasted 2 to 3 hours trying to figure this out. The problem is that the filename looks exactly the same. But there was an extra space somewhere.

**Another Tip:** Also to get the download url - open **system** console. Make sure **all messages** are selected and **search for xcode inside the Search box**. Go to xcode simulator download screen, start and stop the download for the simulator you want and check inside console log. You should find the url there.

Answer (score 2):

> so is there any direct link from where i can download the simulator
>   package directly or somewhere at least it shows progress in
>   percentage/size instead just a bar

You can't download the simulators package directly. Instead, you can download the xcodes from developer.apple using [this link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode), which provides you the required simulators.

If you want the old simulators in new Xcode, download the desired Xcode using the above link,after downloading it, Open the DMG or open your existing older Xcode, right click on the Xcode application and click 'Show Package Contents', navigate to:`Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer`, copy the found simulator folder (eg. iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk folder), repeat steps 2 & 3 for your current Xcode application, paste the simulator folder,restarting the Xcode will show you the new added simulators.

Comment: does copying only iPhoneSimulator folder will work or should i need to copy other folders also , as it not shown in list of new Xcode

Comment: yes copying only iPhone simulator folder does not showing that simulator in Xcode. do we have to copy any other folders? I am trying with Xcode 7.0

Answer (score 1):

**Open iPhone 11 iOS 13.6 Simulator with Xcode 12 in Visual Studio for Mac(Xamarin):**

- You have to install both Xcode 12.0 & Xcode 11.6
- First open 11.6 simulator then open visual studio
- Go to Visual Studio Preferences and change Xcode SDK to point Xcode
  11.6 version and Restart studio
- Once it restart again Goto Visual studio preferences and set Xcode
  SDK path to point Xcode 12.0 and Restart it
- Now close 11.6 simulator and after Visual studio starts voila you
  will see iPhone 11 iOS 13.6 Simulator option in list of simulators

> Note: This steps are performed in Visual Studio for Mac 2019

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [xcodes](https://github.com/XcodesOrg/xcodes) tool to download and install wanted runtime !

**List Runtimes**

```bash
xcodes runtimes --include-betas
```

**Install iOS Runtime**

```bash
xcodes runtimes install "iOS 17.0-beta1"
```

I advice you to install aria2 before doing all this.
Enjoy :)

Comment: zsh: command not found: xcodes on ventura

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step to get new simulator with supported/different OS,

- Open Xcode, open preferences, go to the Components section.
- Go back to the Xcode preferences. Start the simulator OS download.
- Now go to simulator open files and open simulator.
- You can see your downloaded OS, Run and Test.

Answer (score 0):

New Xcode 14.1:

- open setting / platforms: click add and you will find all type of simulators [Xcode setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZyEz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download iOS Simulator file
2. double click on iOS_17.2_Simulator_Runtime.dmg
3. after open .dmg file , copy folder (runtimes) +file (iOS 17.2.simruntime) to path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnNU7.png)

Comment: link download https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/iOS_17.2_Simulator_Runtime/iOS_17.2_Simulator_Runtime.dmg

Answer (score 0):

After downloading and copy and paste the .dmg file in Downloads folder. If your Xcode does not recognize the .dmg file you should install it manually in the terminal by this command:

> sudo xcrun simctl runtime add "Path to downloaded dmg file"

And after that open your Xcode and your simulator would be recognized.

Answer (score -1):

Often, what it takes with Xcode is a good 'ol fashioned restart. This didn't work for me, so I restarted my MacBook Pro. Now it works :)

It's a quick thing to do when you're stuck.

Answer (score -1):

✅ Use this link can download iOS_17_Simulator_Runtime:
https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/iOS_17_Simulator_Runtime/iOS_17_Simulator_Runtime.dmg

If you can't download it ,you can visit this https://developer.apple.com/download/all/ first,then continue down.

Comment: what about ios 17.2? i can not find ios 17.2 simulator runtime please add it in your answer