# xcode 8 simulators are not available

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8

I have just downloaded the `Xcode 8` and opened my project in it and found that there is no simulator available but only `devices` and `build only devices` option is here.

Tried different solutions as per others suggestions like:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

but nothing works.

P.S: I don't want to install iOS 9 or older version simulators.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: check this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058229/download-xcode-simulator-directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Go to Xcode menu **Window** > **Devices**
And at the left bottom corner select `+` > **Add Simulator**.

In the next screen you can select any simulator and name it as you'd like.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, a simple and perfect solution.