# How to install older iOS runtimes on newer Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have Xcode 10.3

I wish to run an iPad Mini simulator running iOS 9.0.3

However when I go to Preferences > Components the only options are:

```
iOS 12.2 Simulator
iOS 12.1 Simulator
iOS 12.0 Simulator
iOS 11.4 Simulator
iOS 11.3 Simulator
iOS 11.2 Simulator
iOS 11.1 Simulator
iOS 11.0 Simulator
iOS 10.3.1 Simulator
```

There is no 9.0.3. How do I download older simulators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode supports SDK latest three versions of the iOS SDK. The only way to have an access to older simulators is to install older version of Xcode.

Comment: After experimenting a lot and testing with the links posted by @Nullable, I've concluded this seems to be correct. By downgrading Xcode I was able to install the simulators for iOS 9. I also discovered that a physical iOS 9 device will still work with Xcode 10.3, even though it doesn't support an iOS 9 simulator. So I've just been plugging in a physical iPad Mini.

Answer (score 1):

I will make a final summary, there are two ways:

#### 1. I originally provided this, reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058229/download-xcode-simulator-directly)

[This is my download path](https://github.com/HSCOO/iPhoneSimulatorSDK), you can download 9.0

1.1 cd `~/Library/Caches`, find `com.apple.dt.Xcode`, show in package. Paste DMG into the `Downloads` folder (if not created).

1.2 Restart `Xcode`, open the panel `Xcode->Preferences->Components`, you can see `iOS 9.0 Simulator`, click to download

In practice, Xcode 10.3 could not be seen to see the download button of the iOS 9.0 Simulator.

It seems to confirm @Adobels `Xcode supports SDK latest three versions of the iOS SDK`

#### 2. Download `.simruntime` and put it directly into the `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/` folder.

The `Runtimes` folder has all the emulators you installed, suffixed with `.simruntime`.

Apple did not provide the `.simruntime` download address, I downloaded it from the cloud disk shared by others, of course, if you installed the old version of Xcode.

I am working after the test, `iOS 9.0 Simulator` will open the prompt `Safe Area Layout Guide before iOS 9.0`, and finally close the `Safe Area Layout Guide`.

Comment: I'm downloading the DMG now. Are there any special instructions for installing it in Xcode?

Comment: I perfected the answer. I used this method before, but I tested it before I answered it. I found it not working. I hope it will be useful to you.

Comment: So I just took a look in `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode` and there was no `Downloads` directory in there. I tried both creating a `Downloads` directory and pasting the DMG directly into the package. In each case I restarted Xcode, went to `Xcode->Preferences->Components`, and there was no `iOS 9.0 Simulator` there. It seems like Xcode may have dropped support for iOS 9

Comment: I haven't given up yet, I updated my answer and hope to help you. But I saw that you downloaded the old version of `Xcode`, which is also the most direct, but you will have multiple `Xcode`

Comment: While I'm not certain where you would normally download the `.simruntime`, because I installed Xcode 9 and downloaded an iOS 9 simulator, I was able to find the `.simruntime` file already in `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes` -- however when I launch Xcode 10.3 none of my iOS 9 devices show up as run targets.

Comment: @Nullable: The link that you shared has only iOS 12.2. I need iOS 15.7.8 version. Can you expand the list?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey You can find all the emulator download links [here](https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/index2.dvtdownloadableindex), but I didn't find a 15.7.8 version, the closest one is only [15.5](https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK15_5-15.5.1.1653527639.dmg).