# Xcode 13.1 stuck on installing simulator on Apple M1 Pro

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, apple-m1

I'm trying to download and install older simulators like iOS 12.4, after it has downloaded it gets stuck on installing.

I have a MacBook Pro 14" (Apple M1 Pro chip) using Xcode 13.1 on macOS Monterey 12.0.1

I've tried running Xcode in Rosetta mode to no avail.
I've tried the answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058229/download-xcode-simulator-directly) to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue when running Xcode in Rosetta mode.
My way: Just close the simulator and use another one.
It seems an issue on Xcode in Rosetta mode

Answer (score 0):

Updating to Monterey 12.1 resolved the issue.