# How to install iOS 17 beta simulators in Xcode 15 beta

Tags: download, simulator, beta, xcode15, ios17

On the apple developer website I can download Xcode new betas separately from the simulators.

[image: download xcode]
I did exactly that. After downloading Xcode (3.41GB) I downloaded the new iOS 17 beta which was 7.47 GB. After installing the new Xcode, it us prompting me to download again the iOS simulator which I had already downloaded. But when prompted from Xcode the download is also very sluggish and I don't want to wait since I have the simulator DMG in my downloads folder.

I looked here already but it did not help: [Download Xcode simulator directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058229/download-xcode-simulator-directly)

I tried manually to put the content of the .DMG file into the library in Xcode as described by some older posts, like in "Cashes/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/"
but this did not work. Restarting Xcode I had the same prompt asking me to redownload the simulator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a bit of googling I found the answer here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes

Just move to the bottom where it says "Install and manage Simulator runtimes from the command line".

The steps to make it work are:

```bash
// Select  version of Xcode
xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta7.app

// launch it
xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch

// and here I add the path to the simulator I downloaded!
xcrun simctl runtime add "~/Downloads/iOS_17_beta_7_Simulator_Runtime.dmg"
```

This worked great and when I opened Xcode again it did recognize the new runtime!

ps. There is also a great command to download all simulators from the command line directly if you need watchOS too!

```bash
xcodebuild -downloadAllPlatforms
```

Answer (score -1):

As per Apple documentation the following steps should work. [DOC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes)

```
xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app
xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
xcrun simctl runtime add "~/Downloads/iOS_17_beta_Simulator_Runtime.dmg"
```

But unfortunately, this does not work for me.

I found the solution [here](https://lickability.com/blog/how-to-install-ios-17-simulators-in-xcode-15/). I just follow the steps.

1. Right click on the Xcode 15 Beta application and select Show Package
   Content.
2. Double click to open the iOS_17_beta_Simulator_Runtime.dmg file
3. Inside the simulator dmg file, find the Runtime folder. This is the
   folder we are going to copy into Xcode.
4. Place the Runtime folder at Developer → Platforms →
   iPhoneOS.platform → Library → Developer → CoreSimulator → Profiles
   inside the Xcode 15 beta Show Package Contents.

If you move the Xcode-beta application to the Application folder,you can use Finder to go to `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles`.

Restart Xcode if you already have it open, and your iOS simulators will be there.